# Stumped by math: Adjust alpha based on UIGestureRecognizer panning

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I’m fairly certain there is an obvious answer to be had here, and perhaps I’m just too tired to see it, but here goes:

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. It’s wired up to move a view around.

I have a subview in this view, that I’d like to adjust the `alpha` of, when the view is being panned.

The view can only be panned horizontally, so that eliminates some math.

The subview in question begins with an `alpha` of `1.0`. While the superview is panning, I would like to adjust the alpha of the subview so that it is proportionally lower and lower, until it reaches a minimum `alpha` of `0.3`.

My code is not much at this point, but effectively looks like this:

```
- (void) someMethodForRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    // do stuff here

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // do fancy math here
    }

    // do more stuff here
}
```

**What kind of fancy math do I need to be doing to calculate the correct `alpha` to apply at any given moment during `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`?**

(Assume that the relevant state-related ivars are set and available, and feel free to add any that may not seem obvious.)

(I’m really a lazy idiot, aren’t I?)

Comment: What is the relationship between the pan distance an the alpha? So should it get more transparent as you move away from the origin? What's the most distance it can move? When do you want it to reach 0.3 alpha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `translationInView:` property to find out how far you have panned. The x value of this point is your horizontal movement. Take the absolute value of this, and find it as a proportion of whatever distance you want to give the minimum alpha. Multiply this proportion by (1 - minAlpha), subtract it from 1.0 and set your subview's alpha to this value.

Pseudocode:

```
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self];
CGFloat x = fabsf(translation.x);
CGFloat proportion = x / MIN_ALPHA_DISTANCE;
CGFloat alphaDifference = proportion * (1 - MIN_ALPHA);
subview.alpha = 1 - alphaDifference;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out. I replaced your MIN_ALPHA_DISTANCE with screen.bounds.size.width to get my desired behavior, and now it works beautifully! :D

Comment: I assume that MIN_ALPHA (not MIN_ALPHA_DISTANCE) is the same as MIN_ALPHA_DISTANCE? In this case, self.view.frame.size.width?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind me suggesting a slightly different approach, I would use an NSTimer (`+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`).

```
- (void) someMethodForRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            self.panStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
            self.panView = recognizer.view;
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(panIntervalWithTimer:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            // Your current pan handler
            break;

        default:
            self.panView.alpha = 1.0;
            self.panView = nil;
            self.panStartTime = 0;

            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)panIntervalWithTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSTimeInterval interval = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.panStartTime;
    CGFloat alpha = 1 - interval; // or some better math
    if (alpha > 0.3) {
        self.panView.alpha = alpha;
    } else {
        self.panView.alpha = 0.3;

        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

**Updated with an invalidate built into the timer and fixed some bugs.**

---

**Updated the code with a new idea.**

How about reducing the alpha by a set amount at every callback. When the user pauses, the alpha stop decreasing. If the rate is set at 0.025, that gives 28 updates before 0.3 is reached. If the rate is 0.001, that gives 70 updates.

```
- (void) someMethodForRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    …

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGFloat alpha = recognizer.view.alpha - kAlphaDecrementRate;
        recognizer.view.alpha = MAX(alpha, 0.3);
    } else {
        recognizer.view.alpha = 1.0;
    }

    …
}
```

Comment: Pardon my bluntness, but I fail to see how this is relevant, although it is quite interesting. Why do I need a timer, when I already have a live user interaction? I want the alpha of the subview to be directly affected by the state of the user’s action.

Comment: @abrahamvegh It's OK if you don't want to use the NSTimer. I would use it one reason. It separates the number of times alpha is set from the number of pan updates. For example, if the user begins a pan, then holds still for a second, you may not get any pan updates. Then the selected view's alpha would not get updated. In essence, it prevents you from getting too many or too few alpha updates.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I’m trying to mimic the behavior of the iOS Springboard, which halts alpha changes if the user stops moving.

Comment: @abrahamvegh I added in a new idea.

Comment: Jeffery Thomas: Thanks for your ideas! @jrturton had exactly what I was thinking of, but couldn’t figure out the math to express. Your approach is useful for other cases, but it has too many “magic numbers” for my use case.